# How to select ranges from multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want to copy the same thing into different rows in Excel. How can I simplify the code below so I can select multiple ranges?

```
Windows("Schedule.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("QF.IPP").Select
Range("E10:K10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("ID_DOG.xlsm").Activate
Range("B47:G47").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Windows("Schedule.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("QF.IPP").Select
Range("E10:K10").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("ID_DOG.xlsm").Activate
Range("B48:G48").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* paste a row into mutliple rows provided the same number of columns is preserved (that's why below I paste into columns "B:H" instead of "B:G"):

```
Workbooks("Schedule.xlsx").Sheets("QF.IPP").Range("E10:K10").Copy
Workbooks("ID_DOG.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Range("B47:H48").PasteSpecial
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to select, copy, and paste: you can change the values of cells directly.

`Workbooks("ID_DOG").Sheets("QF.IPP").Range("B47:G48").value2 = Workbooks("Schedule")Sheets("QF.IPP").Range("E10:K10").Value2`

Comment: These are two different excel files. I'm trying to copy the values from the "Schedule.xls" QF.IPP tab and paste them into "ID_DOG.xls"